# ExpressJS router with parameter empty

Tags: node.js, express, rules, isnullorempty

I'm working on my first Rest API with NodeJS using ExpressJS. It's very simple and intuitive.
One of my routing rule is:

```
api.get("/api/plugin/:action", (req,res) => { ... }
```

If I send:

```
http://localhost:3000/api/plugin
```

I got the error:

```
Cannot get /api/plugin/
```

Is ther a way to intercept this single case, excluding the routing without :action? I need to check req.param, and verify the action param, even if it is empty.

Comment: did you try adding a slash after plugin? like http://localhost:3000/api/plugin//

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use `?` in route to make your parameter optional

```
api.get("/api/plugin/:action?", (req,res) => { ... }
```

Answer (score 1):

You have 2 options:

1. use optional path param with `?`, like this

```
api.get("/api/plugin/:action?", (req,res) => { ... }
```

2. use query params, like this:

```
api.get("/api/plugin/", (req,res) => { ... }
```

and call:

```
http://localhost:3000/api/plugin?action=
```

and check in **req.query** object